# Multi-level Inheritance with TPT Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I have the following:

```
public class Entity<TKey> : IEntity
{              
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
    public virtual StateEnum State { get; set; }}


 public class Party : Entity<int>
{
    public virtual int TypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string MobileNo1 { get; set; }}


public class Person : Party
{
    public virtual int PartyId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }}
```

I have in sql Party table contains the following columns [Id,TypedId,MobileNo1]
and Person table contains the following columns:[PartyId,Name] and PartyId is foreign key for Id of Party .

How to make the mapping ? I have tried but i'm not reach to any thing.

**Edit**

suppose that TKey is integer
and the PartyId is key of person and foreign key to party

I try to make map for person

HasKey(p => p.PartyId);
ToTable("Person");

and to party

```
   HasKey(p => p.Id);
            ToTable("Party");
```

and its not work, how I make mapping in this case ?

**Edit 2:**

I have the following

```
 public class Entity<TKey> : IEntity
    {              
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
        public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
        public virtual StateEnum State { get; set; }}


     public class Person : Entity<int>
    {
        public virtual string FirstName{ get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName{ get; set; }
}


    public class Employee: Person 
    {
        public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual string CompanyName{ get; set; }
}
```

I have Person table contain [Id,FirstName,LastName]
I have Employee table contain [PersonId,FirstName,LastName]

-- PersonId is foreign key to person table.
-- employee is a person the relationship is one to one.
--for future i can add Student entity , so Student is person

**How I can make mapping ?**

Comment: Is there a reason an `Employee` should be both a person and have a link to a person? Why are you having `PersonId` on `Employee`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
public class Entity<TKey> : IEntity
{              
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
public TKey Id { get; set; }
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
public StateEnum State { get; set; }}


public class Party : Entity<int>
{
public int TypeId { get; set; }
public string MobileNo1 { get; set; }

public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
}


public class Person
{
public int PartyId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public virtual Party Party {get; set;}
}
```

So Person has a party (if it's optional you declare `int?`) and Party inherits from Entity. I also removed a lot of virtual declarations which probably make no sense (correct me if I'm wrong on some of them). The `virtual` keyword is used in Entity Framework to indicate a navigation property. So those properties are "links" to other existing entities. (Also assumed that `PartyId` is the primary key for `Person`).

I'm not sure this will work though because of the `TKey` primary key in `Party` (if you declare no primary key yourself EF automatically picks a property with "id" in the name) can be a different type and the foreignkey from Person is always an `int`... Why can't you just declare the Id as `int`?

EDIT: 1:1 relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .ToTable("Person")
            .HasKey(p => p.PartyId)
            .HasRequired(p => p.Party)
            .WithRequiredDependent(p => p.Person)
            .Map(pers => pers.MapKey("PartyId");
```

That should normally work. It basically says Person needs to have a party and party needs a person. Because Person has the foreign key, it is the dependent.

You will also need to update your models without all the virtual properties and add virtual property to the corresponding entities (like in models I posted).It would be a lot easier to just use the attributes though and leave the fluent api as it is for this one:

```
public class Entity<TKey> : IEntity
{              
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
public TKey Id { get; set; }
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute]
public StateEnum State { get; set; }}


public class Party : Entity<int>
{
public int TypeId { get; set; }
public string MobileNo1 { get; set; }

public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
}


public class Person
{
[Key,ForeignKey("Party")]
public int PartyId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public virtual Party Party {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: thank you Alexander , please check my edit on the question :)

Comment: @Doha i'll edit my answer, can person have multiple parties or party multiple persons? You're not really clear what relationship they have

Comment: person have one party .it is one to one relationship , it is like employee is person .

Comment: @Doha but party doesn't need to have a person? It's optional?

Comment: yes, if i have person there is must  have party , ; if i create person io must create party , if i create party it need to have person , maybe party assign to car for example

Comment: thank you, but you remove the inheritance of person from party , I don't to make inheritance throw the polymorphism.

Comment: There's something wrong with your design, if Person inherits from Party it will have a primary key `PartyId` and primary key `Id`. That is still possible when you make it a composite key, but you can't have `PartyId` as a foreignkey to that same table then. I don't know what you're trying to do but it's not possible :)

Comment: thank you ; i want to ask you if i remove PartyId  from person class , and rename PartyId  to Id in Person table in DB , it will work by inheritance ?

Comment: You can make Person inherit from Entity<T> but not from Party afaik because they both have different tables. I think you're making this overcomplicated, what are you trying to do with the inheritance between person and party?

Comment: I update the question look at Edit2 ,,, maybe will understand me what I want  now :)